# How would I find the value of $\cos^{-1}(\cos(30))$ ? I get two possible answers :(

Tags: trigonometry

$30$ radians lie in-between $9\pi$ and $10\pi$ so will $\cos^{-1}(\cos(30))$ be $10\pi-30$ or $30-9\pi$ and why ?

Comment: You usually say $\cos^{-1}(x) \in [0,\pi]$  at least when $x \in [-1,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition to be satisfied is that $0\le\arccos(\cos30)\le\pi$.

Now a basic calculator shows that

- $30-9\pi=1.725\,666\dots$
- $10\pi-30=1.415\,926\dots,$

so both solutions satisfy them.

Anyway, it results from elementary trigonometry that
$$\cos(\theta+n\pi)=\begin{cases}
\cos\theta &\text{ if }n\text{ is even},\\
-\cos\theta &\text{ if }n\text{ is odd}.
\end{cases}$$
and $\cos$ is an even function, so $\cos(10\pi-30)=\cos(30-10\pi)=\cos 30$.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with arcsine. I'll fix that instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously it will be the one whose cosine is equal to $\cos(30)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\cos(30-9\pi)$ is actually $-\cos30$.